# remove text from notpade++ and keep text starts with

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge text, and I want to remove all text and keep only the lines that start with "http"

How I can do that?

sample data (I want to keep only the URLS):

```
  request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "http://10.0.183.17:8080/arcgis/rest1/services/NJMPROD/Topo_En/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true&callback=OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.registry.c1",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Pragma",
          "value": "no-cache"
        },
      ],
  },
  {
    "startedDateTime": "2015-11-11T04:45:56.321Z",
    "request": {
      "http://10.0.183.17:8080/arcgis/rest1/services/NJMPROD/Satellite_En/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true&callback=OpenLayers.Protocol.Script.registry.c2",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
```

Answer (score 2):

Using some information found from [this post](https://superuser.com/a/558288), you can mark all lines by:

```
Search menu -> Mark
```

In the "Find what" field:

```
\w*"http://.*"
```

Ensure that the "Bookmark line" and "Regular expression" options are checked, then click on "Mark All".

Then you can remove all non-marked lines by:

```
Search menu -> Bookmark -> Remove Unmarked Lines
```

If you literally want just the URL without the quotes and punctuation, you can use replace (ctrl+h) with the following regex:

```
Find what: "|,
Replace with: (leave blank)
```

Then click on "Replace All".  To clean up whitespace, use:

```
Edit menu -> Blank Operations -> Trim Leading and Trailing Space
```

A bit cumbersome if you are limited to using Notepad++. Assuming you're running Windows, you could install Cygwin + GNU utils to have command-line tools such as sed and grep available.

Comment: Great thanks that works

Answer (score 0):

**This solution uses, the Notepad++ Replace functionality:**

1) Open the **Replace** dialog (<kbd>(Strg + H)</kbd>) and enter this expression(into the **"Find what"** field):

```
^(?!\s+"http://).*$
```

> > ***Short Regular Expression Side-Step***
> >     **^**  Beginning of the Line
> >     **(?! ... )**  negative lookahead -> this sequence should not appear
> >     **\s+**  One or more Whitespaces
> >     **"http://** is just the Charactersequence to match (in your case not to match do to the negative lookahead)
> >     **.***  Zero or More Characters
> >     **$** Lineend
> >
> > *Here an online Demo of the Expression https://regex101.com/r/qS5iE1/1
> >
> >     **(This is also a great place to test Expressions)***

2) Clear **"Replace with"** Field *(or leave it blank)* and set **"Regular expression"** Search mode  and click **"Replace All"**
[image: Screenshot Searchbox1]
*(Sorry, that the screenshot is in german)*

3) You are done! :)

4) **Optional:** to remove the white spaces you could do this

[image: screenshot second search]
*(Sorry, that the screenshot is in german)*

**Final Result** of this actions looks like this **(on win7 with notepad++ Version  6.7+)**

[image: screenshot result]
*(Sorry, that the screenshot is in german)*

Comment: It is not working.
^(?!\s+"http://).*$ returns nothing found

Comment: Select the Search mode? Or is the real data not comparable with the smaple data?